# Ruby/Watir : firefox headless

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, headless

according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode firefox 57+, has the ability to run in headless mode.

i tried to use it with this:

`omg3r = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: 'omg3r', args: "-headless"`

and i couldn't find an example to how to properly send arguments to firefox in watir.
help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Watir 6.9 you can try:

```
omg3r = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: 'omg3r', headless: true
```

http://watir.com/watir-6-9/

Comment: looks like I was just too early XD, thanks for sharing, would've taken me like more 2 months to realise it was implemented

Answer (score 1):

example your browser is in case statement as firefox-remote

`when "firefox-remote"
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(args: ['-headless'])
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, options: options`